# Why is my application loading my files twice?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment

In my application I have my own custom filetype. I have it set to detect whether the application was started from a file being opened in the explorer or if it was just opened up from the assembly. All is working pretty good, except when one of my files is opened from outside the application, it opens the application up like it should and loads the file into the text editor in my application, like it should. Except the only problem is it loads the file into the text editor twice. I can't figure out why. Could anyone shed some light?

The code is being called in an override that acts as a form load. The reason for this is because my start up form is invisible on startup, except it shows the notify icon so things can be done, or the form can be shown. The only other spot that uses some of this code is when a menu item is clicked in a context menu, although that opens up a openfiledialog and then opens the file in the dialog.

EDIT:  Added the rest of the code in the sub.

**I found a solution to my issue, I have answered my own question with the fix. I wan't to thank anyone who has helped.
 Also, I want to thank Hans Passant as he is the author of the override code seen here. This allows for the start up form to stay invisible, while showing the notify icon still.**

```
     Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)

    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        Me.CreateHandle()
        value = False
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
    If (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Length > 1) Then

        Dim s As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)

        Using sr As New StreamReader(s)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                Dim item As New ListViewItem
                item.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine())
                ListView3.Items.Add(item)
            End While
        End Using
        For I = 0 To ListView3.Items.Count - 1
            ListView3.Items(I).Text = CStr(I)
        Next
    End If
```

**Answer can be seen below.**

Comment: How is this snippet of code getting called?

Comment: it there any other place that calls this code, or that touches the listview in any manner?

Comment: I added some more information, thank you in advance for the help guys.

Comment: Well does that code get called twice?

Comment: Check Listview2.Items Count at the start and end

Comment: Attribution is required at stackoverflow.com.  Which also helps a lot to make SO users understand what your code means.  The odds you'll get a good answer are slim.

Comment: Attribution? as in posting where the code originates? The only part that came from anywhere was from here and that was the override code. Anywho I found a solution to my issue. I created a boolean that allows the code to fire only once. I will do a follow up answer.

Comment: And that code came from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to my issue. I found out that it was indeed the code firing twice. Most likely to do with the override. Still not 100% sure though. I created a boolean to only allow the code to fire once. It works great now. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

```
     Protected Overrides Sub SetVisibleCore(ByVal value As Boolean)
    Static blnExecuted As Boolean
    If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
        Me.CreateHandle()
        value = False
    End If
    MyBase.SetVisibleCore(value)
    If (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Length > 1) Then

        Dim s As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)
        If blnExecuted = False Then
            blnExecuted = True
            Using sr As New StreamReader(s)
                While Not sr.EndOfStream
                    Dim item As New ListViewItem
                    item.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine())
                    ListView3.Items.Add(item)
                End While
            End Using
            For I = 0 To ListView3.Items.Count - 1
                ListView3.Items(I).Text = CStr(I)
            Next
        End If

    Else
        openscriptfunc()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt help with your issue, but a little refactoring and you can avoid the second loop:

```
With ListView3.Items.Add(ListView3.Items.Count)
  .Subitems.Add(sr.ReadLine())
End With
```